# unbiased estimate for household size

Tags: estimation, sampling, bias

We have a population of N people. They live in households of varying sizes: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. We are going to do a random telephone survey and ask them how big their household size is. What are the biases? What is an unbiased estimate for the average household size?

Comment: Is this a homework exercise? If so please tag it as `[self-study]` and check http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: This question appears to be a carryover from the days, which ended a couple decades ago, when it might be reasonable to assume most households had only one phone number. Today the number of phones is related not only to the size of the household but also to its location, ages of the inhabitants, and their purchasing power. As such this is an interesting and complex situation but is scarcely suitable for a textbook problem: obtaining that unbiased estimate would require considerable sophistication and resources.

Comment: Note that if a village had half its households size $2$ and half size $6$ (so three-quarters of the inhabitants of the village lived in households size $6$), and you asked everybody in the village (e.g. stopping them in the street) then the average response would be $5$, while if you knocked at each door and asked the person opening the door, the average response would be $4$

Comment: @Henry. I think we need find a weight to change the counts for households size 2, households size 3....